# Set state in ReactJS after receiving data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem when using `setUsers` in the below example. The first api call is returning two courses and I need to get data for each users that is related to the course.

Only one users is set in `users` when calling `setUsers([...users, user])` in the for loop.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    try {
        const doc = await getDocument(searchObj) //returning two documents
        if (doc.status === 200) {
            for (let course of doc.data.course) {
                const user = await getUser(course.document.userId)
                if (user.status === 200) { //status 200 for both requests
                    setUsers([...users, user]) //only one gets set
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

Comment: calling setUsers(...) triggers a re-render of the React component, so the for loop never ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this...

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    try {
        const doc = await getDocument(searchObj) //returning two documents
        if (doc.status === 200) {
          let userArray = [];
          for (let course of doc.data.course) {
              const user = await getUser(course.document.userId)
              if (user.status === 200) { //status 200 for both requests
                userArray.push(user);
              }
          }
          setUsers(userArray)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```